# When program is expected to loop through again based on user input, it instead results in Segmentation Fault: 11

Tags: c++, oop

I have made a simple rock-paper-scissors program in C++ and have tried to implement the main.cpp file in such a way that after playing a game, the user is asked for input if they want to play again. A response of 'y' should run through the program again allowing the user to enter another name and move choice, however the program will only run successfully once and then result in:  RUN FINISHED: segmentation fault : 11.

Code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "rock-paper-scissorss.h"
using namespace std;

void whoWon(string player_move, string computer_move){
    if(player_move == "rock"){
        if(computer_move == "paper")
            cout<<"You chose rock and the computer chose paper, the computer wins!"<<endl;

        else if(computer_move == "scissors")
            cout<<"You chose rock and the computer chose scissors, you win!"<<endl;

        else
            cout<<"You chose rock and the computer chose rock, it's a tie!"<<endl;
    }

    else if(player_move == "paper"){
        if(computer_move == "scissors")
            cout<<"You chose paper and the computer chose scissors, the computer wins!"<<endl;

        else if(computer_move == "rock")
            cout<<"You chose paper and the computer chose rock, you win!"<<endl;

        else
            cout<< "You chose paper and the computer chose paper, it's a tie!"<<endl;
    }

    else{
        if(computer_move == "rock")
            cout<<"You chose scissors and the computer chose rock, the computer wins!"<<endl;

        else if(computer_move == "paper")
            cout<<"You chose scissors and the computer chose paper, you win!"<<endl;

        else
            cout<<"You chose scissors and the computer chose scissors, it's a tie!"<<endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  char play_again = 'y';

  while(play_again == 'y'){
    cout<<"Please enter your name: "<<endl;
    string name;
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Hello "<<name<<", welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors!"<<endl;

    Player player_1(name);

    cout<<"Please enter the move you wish to make: "<<endl;
    string move;
    getline(cin,move);
    while(1){
        if((move == "rock") || (move == "paper") || (move == "scissors")){

            player_1.setMoveChoice(move);
            break;
        }

        else{
            cout<<"Invalid move choice! Please enter rock, paper, or scissors"<<endl;
            getline(cin,move);
        }
    } 


    Computer com_1;
    com_1.setMoveChoice();

   string p_move = player_1.getMoveChoice();
   string c_move = com_1.getMoveChoice();


   whoWon(p_move,c_move);



   cout<<"Would you like to play again?(y/n)"<<endl;

   cin>>play_again;
   cout<<"your response was: "<<play_again<<endl;



    } 



 return 0;
}
```

rock-paper-scissors.cpp:

```
#include "rock-paper-scissorss.h"
#include <cstdlib>

Computer :: Computer(){
    num_generated = rand() % 3 + 1;
}

void Computer ::  setMoveChoice(){
   if(num_generated == 1)
       move_selected = "rock";

   else if(num_generated == 2)
       move_selected = "paper";

   else
       move_selected = "scissors";

}

string Computer :: getMoveChoice(){
    return move_selected;
}

Computer :: ~Computer(){

    delete this;
}


Player :: Player(string name){
    player_name = name;

}

void Player :: setMoveChoice(string choice){
    move_selected = choice;
}

string Player :: getMoveChoice(){
    return move_selected;
}

Player :: ~Player(){
    delete this;
}
```

rock-paper-scissorss.h:

```
#ifndef ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORSS_H
#define ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORSS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class Computer{

private:
    int num_generated;
    string move_selected;

public:
    Computer();
    void setMoveChoice();
    string getMoveChoice();
    ~Computer();
};

class Player{

private:
    string move_selected;
    string player_name;

public:
    Player(string);
    void setMoveChoice(string move);
    string getMoveChoice();
    ~Player();
};

#endif /* ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORSS_H */
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class does not need a destructor, as it never explicitly allocates any resources. Remove:

```
  Computer :: ~Computer(){
      delete this;
  }
```

and all similar functions.

And be aware that even if your class did need a destructor, the destructor should not call:

```
delete this;
```

as this will effectively be performed for you by code emitted by the compiler. The destructor should only `delete` resources you explicitly allocated, within the object being destroyed, with  `new`.